# jQuery slide toggle change image onclick

Tags: jquery, xhtml, slidetoggle

I'm using .slideToggle to show/hide content when an image is clicked, it changes once when the content shows but doesn't change back to the original image when its clicked again to hide the content, not quite sure what I'm missing here. Any help much appreciated.

the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#toggle1').click(function() {
        $('.toggle1').slideToggle('1100');
        $("#bg").attr('src',"images/box-arrow-down.jpg");
        return false;

    });
```

the HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <div style="width:1100px;height:100px;margin-left:40px;">
    <span style="float:left;"><a href="#" id="toggle1"><img src="images/box-arrow-up.jpg" height="16" width="17" alt="arrow" id="bg" style="margin-top:40px;" /></a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle1" style="display:none;width:1100px;padding:0px;margin-left:8px;">
  <div class="boxTime">09:00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not reference the original `src`.  You can go about this in hundreds of different ways... but here are a couple examples.

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle1').click(function() {
        $('.toggle1').slideToggle('1100');
        var src = $("#bg").attr('src') == "images/box-arrow-down.jpg" ? "images/box-arrow-up.jpg" : "images/box-arrow-down.jpg";
        $("#bg").attr('src', src);
        return false;

    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/NCqRk/

Or something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var originalImage = $("#bg").attr('src');

    $('#toggle1').click(function() {
        $('.toggle1').slideToggle('1100');
        var src = $("#bg").attr('src') == originalImage ? "images/box-arrow-down.jpg" : originalImage;
        $("#bg").attr('src', src);
        return false;

    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/NCqRk/1/

Comment: thanks, thats great, it makes sense now. I've actually hit upon another issue, I want to slide toggle multiple divs independently using the same function, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I tried using classes instead of IDs but couldn't get it to work. This example is using a function for each block of divs with a different ID, seems like not a very efficient way of doing it,  http://jsfiddle.net/TyjRv/3/